# The safeAreaInsets is not updating as expected

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, background, foreground

I have a side menu controller that is controlling two view controllers. One of those view controllers hides the navigation bar so that it can use the full screen. I added a tap gesture to be able to switch to other VCs. The safeAreaInsets are as expected UNLESS I background the app. If I background the app while a VC with the navigation bar visible is shown, everything works fine, and when I switch to the other one, the bar is hidden and I see a full screen. However, if I background the app while the full screen VC is showing, when I foreground the app again and switch to the other VC, unhiding the navigation bar, the safeAreaInsets are wrong. This can be "corrected" by backgrounding the app and foregrounding it again whence the safeAreaInsets are correct again.

Is there some way to force a safeAreaInsets update?

If I

```
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
```

this method is called when I background the app, but not when the navigation bar is hidden or unhidden.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. On the parent view controller I do this when hiding/unhiding the navigation bar:

```
view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```